# Grab properties of the HTML __data__ property using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, d3.js, svg, geojson

I am trying to get hold of a property inside a `<g>` tag

Here are the properties of the g [tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm6yd.png):

I want to grab the property: ward

All the g tags have click events but I'm not able to grab on to the ward value that I need for an ajax request, here the js:

```
$(".map-wrapper").on("click", "g", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("I want this to be the value of the ward property");
 });
```

The nested query is something like ["**data**"]["properties"]["ward"]

Comment: why not get the data directly using d3? Something like `allgs.forEach(function(g) {console.log(d3.select(g).data())})`

Comment: can you use jquery's .prop() to get it? http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: So this is what i did to get the value I needed


`$(".map-wrapper").on("click", "g", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $ward = $(this);
  console.log($ward[0].__data__.properties.ward);
 })'code`

Comment: @Cyril and JordanHendrix, thanks for the suggestions, I tried both of them but couldn't get um to work...

Answer (score 2):

```
 d3.selectAll(".map-wrapper").on("click", "g", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var ward = d3.select($(this)).data().ward; 
 });
```

This should give you the ward for the clicked `g` element

Answer (score 1):

So the answer to my question was to isolate the `g` tag, then access its `__data__` property, then access the `properties` property of `__data__`, then access the `ward` property of `properties`.

```
$(".map-wrapper").on("click", "g", function(event) { 
     event.preventDefault(); 
     $ward = $(this); 
     console.log($ward[0].__data__.properties.ward); 
});
```

Comment: If you are using d3 then utilize its power.

Comment: So here's what I did to use your method, what are the benefits of using d3 instead of jquery?     

     d3.selectAll(".map-wrapper").on("click", "g", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
           var ward = d3.select($(this)).data().ward; 

            var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            url: "wards/" + ward,
           type: 'get'
        });

        ajaxRequest.done(function (jsonWardCrimeData) {          
          $('.load-animation').toggle();
          $('.specific-data').html(jsonWardCrimeData);
        });
 });